# for..in loop for asynchronous tasks in Javascript

Tags: javascript, foreach, promise, hashmap

I have an associative container (key/value, "hash"). I iterate over it using the for..in loop:

```
for (key in container) {
   doSomethingWith(key, container[key]
}
```

Now I want doSomethingWith() to return a promise (Q or the standard one), and I want to iterate sequentially, not in parallel. That is, I want every call of doSomethingWith() to resolve its promise before calling it again.

How do I do it?

1. Is there a way to iterate over keys without resorting to Object.keys() (which in my case is pretty long) and indices? Are new Map class helpful?
2. It may be already written by someone. Also, if I want to have a limited concurrency (e.g. 10 somethingWith() in progress, in the spirit of make -j 10), the complexity explodes, so a mature implementation must exist somewhere.
3. How exactly do I chain it? My take is to use a helper function which calls itself from done():

---

```
function forEachKey(obj, doSomething) {
    const q = Q.defer()
    const keys = Object.keys(obj)
    const idx = 0
    const helper = () =>
       if (idx < keys.length) {
           doSomething(idx).done(helper)
           idx += 1
       }
       else
       {
          q.resolve()
       }
}
```

Comment: Just use `async`/`await`. It's the simplest and most efficient solution.

Comment: To sequentially resolve a set of promises, you could do `Object.keys(obj).reduce((p, k) => p.then(() => doSomething(k)), Promise.resolve())`

Comment: `Array.prototype.reduce()` is synchronous. I can use neither it nor foreach. If yielding from within for..in is supported, it may be promising. I'll give it a try

Comment: Yes, the iteration is synchronous, but the resolution is asynchronous. I have not yet had a chance to play around with [async iterators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for-await...of) since they're still in draft.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for-await...of

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its a very simple demo, but I think this shows how async/await can be used to acheive what you need.

```js
const container = {
  name: "test",
  value: "test2"
};

const doSomethingWith = (x, y) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  console.log(x);
  resolve(x);
});

(async() => {
  for (let key in container) {
    await doSomethingWith(key, container[key]);
  }
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to make a chain of promises. Here's an example with reduce:

```
Object.keys(obj).reduce((promiseSoFar, key) => 
  promiseSoFar.then(() => doSomethingWith(key, container[key])
, Promise.resolve());
```

> Is there a way to iterate over keys without resorting to Object.keys() (which in my case is pretty long) and indices

I'm not sure what the aversion to Object.keys is, but yes, you can build then chain of promises without Object.keys

```
let promiseSoFar = Promise.resolve();
for (let key in container) {
   promiseSoFar = promiseSoFar.then(() => doSomethingWith(key, container[key]));
}
```

Comment: There are hundred thousand to hundred million keys. So the promise chain or Object.keys may weigh a lot.

Answer (score 1):

As I'm on node 4.9.1 I'm unable to use async/await. So here is my own take using `yield`:

```
function* keyGenerator(obj)
{
    for (const key in obj)
    {
        yield key
    }
}

exports.asyncForIn = function (obj, doSomething)
{
    const keyGen = keyGenerator(obj)
    const q = Q.defer()

    const rec = () => {
        const i = keyGen.next()
        if (!i.done)
        {
            doSomething(i.value).done(rec, (x) => q.reject(x))
        }
        else
        {
            q.resolve()
        }
    }
    rec()
    return q.promise
}
```